# Calling address book contacts in Skype 4

Tags: skype

I've just updated to the new [Skype 4](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12288/getting-started-with-skype-4-for-android-phones) on my Nexus 4. I regularly use Skype to call numbers saved  in my phone's address book contacts, but can't find where to do this in the new version.

The previous version of Skype 3.2 had an address book icon at the top right ([as seen here](https://support.skype.com/library/SKYPE/Images/FAQs/FA12089/FA12089_a.png)) but this is missing in the new Skype 4 ([as seen here](https://support.skype.com/library/SKYPE/screenshots/FA12287/FA12287-b.png)). Is there no longer a way to call my phone's address book contacts without adding them as a [Skype contact](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12287/calling-mobiles-and-landlines-with-skype-4-for-android-phones) as well?

I'd rather not set Skype to sync my contacts as I regularly jump back and forth between personal & work accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Sky Dialer for Skype](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nimeshm.skydialer) App, It lets you make Skype calls to your android contacts without even going to the Skype app(It requires the Skype app to be installed to work), lets you mark and organize favorites for easy calling too.

Full Disclosure: I am the app's developer